# Get date from earthtool - PHP & XML parsing

Tags: php, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

I found this web service which provides the date time of a timezone. http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1/24.0167/89.8667

I want to call it & get the values like isotime with php.

So I tried

```
$contents = simplexml_load_file("http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1/24.0167/89.8667");

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML( $contents );
```

AND also with

```
file_get_contents
```

With `file_get_contents` it gets only a string of numbers not the XML format. Something like this

```
1.0 24.0167 89.8667 6 F 20 Feb 2014 13:50:12 2014-02-20 13:50:12 +0600 2014-02-20 07:50:12 Unknown
```

Nothing worked. Can anyone please help me that how can I get the isotime or other values from that link using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works):

```
$url = 'http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1/24.0167/89.8667';
$nodes = array('localtime', 'isotime', 'utctime');
$cont = file_get_contents($url);
$node_values = array();
if ($cont && ($xml = simplexml_load_string($cont))) {
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        if ($xml->$node) $node_values[$node] = (string)$xml->$node;
    }
}

print_r($node_values);
```